# How to Expand/Collapse android component in Material Design

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library

How to Expand/Collapse android component like `ImageView`, `GoogleMap` .. etc
I am using Design support library to provide `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout` to Collapse `ToolBar`.

But how to Collapse other component.
Also I Haven't depth knowledge of Design support library, If it is possible to Collapse component using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` then give me some sample or Example.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: here's a blog that could help http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en. There are third party libraries released even before the support design library. You can find them on github if your interested.

Comment: Thank you for given blog link @Raghunandan...

Answer (score 0):

Views inside a CoordinatorLayout negotiate with others in order to work together effectively by specifying these [Behaviors](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html)

A CoordinatorLayout is a super cool feature of Material Design that helps to create attractive and harmonized layouts.

All you have to do is wrap your child views inside the CoordinatorLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout        
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 tools:context="com.byte64.coordinatorlayoutexample.ScollingActivity">

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">



        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scolling" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and content_scrolling:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView     
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
 tools:context="com.byte64.coordinatorlayoutexample.ScollingActivity"
 tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scolling">

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:text="@string/large_text" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

What this gives us is a layout that can be scrolled to collapse the Toolbar and hide the FloatingActionButton

**Open:**

[image]

**Closed:**

[image]